# can apache pig compare unicode string?

Tags: apache-pig

I have a file with these data:

```
jumpsuit    1
son 1
Đồng hồ kim 1
```

This is my pig script:

```
A = LOAD 'hdfs://Hadoop238:8020/user/steve/test/test.txt' USING PigStorage AS (productName:chararray, number:int);

B = FILTER A BY (productName =='Đồng hồ kim');

DUMP B;
```

It returned nothing. But if i change to:

```
B = FILTER A BY (productName =='jumpsuit');
```

It returned value.

It seems pig can not compare unicode string. Is there any way to compare unicode string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On UTF-8 systems you can specify:

- String constants consisting of printable ASCII characters such as 'abc'.
- You can specify control characters such as '\t'.
- And you can specify a character in Unicode by starting it with '\u', for instance, '\u0001' represents Ctrl-A in hexadecimal.

You should use `\u0110\u1ED3ng h\u1ED3 kim` for `Đồng hồ kim`

So this is lil pain but you can convert that charachters in unicode and pass it as argument.

In theory, you should be able to specify non-UTF-8 constants on non-UTF-8 systems but as far as we know this has not been tested.